# Why does specifying a Method Receiver sometimes trigger an 'undefined' error?

Tags: go

I thought I understood Go's classes and Method Receivers, but apparently not. They generally work intuitively, but here's an example where using one appears to cause an 'undefined: Wtf' error:

```
package main

type Writeable struct {
    seq int
}

func (w Writeable) Wtf() { // causes a compile error
//func Wtf() { // if you use this instead, it works
}

func Write() {
    Wtf() // this is the line that the compiler complains about
}

func main() {
}
```

I am using a compiler downloaded from golang within the last month or so, and LiteIDE. Please explain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining Wtf() as a method of Writeable.  Then you're trying to use it without a struct instance.  I changed your code below to create a struct and then use Wtf() as the method of that struct. Now it compiles.  http://play.golang.org/p/cDIDANewar

```
package main

type Writeable struct {
    seq int
}

func (w Writeable) Wtf() { // causes a compile error
//func Wtf() { // if you use this instead, it works
}

func Write() {
    w := Writeable{}
    w.Wtf() // this is the line that the compiler complains about
}

func main() {
}
```

Comment: These things always seem so obvious in retrospect, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The point about the receiver is that you must call the function on it with `receiver.function()`

If you want `Wtf` to be callable without a receiver, change its declaration to

```
func Wtf() {
```

If you want to call it without changing it, you may write

```
 Writeable{}.Wtf()
```

Comment: Thank you for a helpful and fast reply.